# What kind of Ethernet cable is needed for Windbg?

Tags: visual-studio-debugging, ethernet

I’m looking to do some kernel mode debugging using a network cable.
Exactly what kind of cable is required ? Will a straight-through cable work or do I need a special cable to accomplish this ?

Comment: Any proper cable will do.

Comment: @Zac67 please post comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Any proper cable should do - category 5e or better for 100 or 1000 Mbit/s aka 100BASE-TX or 1000BASE-T.

A straight standard patch cable should be fine. If you don't use a switch in between, the link should come up all the same, as Auto MDI-X (auto crossover) is nearly ubiquitous. If the link doesn't come up you'll need a crossover cable or adapter.